# Small Basic How do I get my players square to "die" even if my enemies square can't be matched up exactly to it?

Tags: if-statement, graphics, game-physics, shapes, smallbasic

Here's the code:

```
'Player and Enemy Variables
PlayerX = 0
PlayerY = 339
EnemyX = Math.GetRandomNumber(590)
EnemyY = 339
'Just setting up
GraphicsWindow.Show()
GraphicsWindow.Width = "600"
GraphicsWindow.Height = "400"
GraphicsWindow.KeyDown = OnKeyDown
'Ground, Enemy, and Player Drawn
GraphicsWindow.FillRectangle(0,350,600,50)
GraphicsWindow.DrawRectangle(PlayerX,PlayerY,10,10)
GraphicsWindow.DrawRectangle(EnemyX,EnemyY,10,10)
GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(50,50,100,"WASD")
Sub OnKeyDown
  'What button was pressed? 
  If (GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "W") Then
    GraphicsWindow.Clear()
    PlayerY = PlayerY - 10
    GraphicsWindow.FillRectangle(0,350,600,50)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawRectangle(PlayerX,PlayerY,10,10)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawRectangle(EnemyX,EnemyY,10,10)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(50,50,100,"WASD")
  EndIf
  If (GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "S") Then
    GraphicsWindow.Clear()
    PlayerY = PlayerY + 10
    GraphicsWindow.FillRectangle(0,350,600,50)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawRectangle(PlayerX,PlayerY,10,10)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawRectangle(EnemyX,EnemyY,10,10)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(50,50,100,"WASD")
  EndIf
  If (GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "A") Then
    GraphicsWindow.Clear()
    PlayerX = PlayerX - 10
    GraphicsWindow.FillRectangle(0,350,600,50)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawRectangle(PlayerX,PlayerY,10,10)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawRectangle(EnemyX,EnemyY,10,10)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(50,50,100,"WASD")
  EndIf
  If (GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "D") Then
    GraphicsWindow.Clear()
    PlayerX = PlayerX + 10
    GraphicsWindow.FillRectangle(0,350,600,50)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawRectangle(PlayerX,PlayerY,10,10)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawRectangle(EnemyX,EnemyY,10,10)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(50,50,100,"WASD")
  EndIf
  'Keep in the Graphics Window!
  If (PlayerX < 10) Then
    PlayerX = 10
  EndIf
  If (PlayerX > 590) Then
    PlayerX = 590
  EndIf
  If (PlayerY < 10) Then
    PlayerY = 10
  EndIf
  If (PlayerY > 339) Then
   PlayerY = 339
  EndIf
  'Player and Enemy Collide.
  If (PlayerX = EnemyX And PlayerY = EnemyY) Then
    GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(100,50,100,"NO!")
  EndIf

EndSub
```

And heres the problem. 
To make it look nice and not be super slow, whenever the Player is moved, it's moved in multiples of 10. However the Enemy's X axis is random, and not always on a multiple of 10. What I'm trying to do is whenever my Player's square is inside my Enemy's square, it will display "NO!" on the Graphics Window. But I can't unless the random number that the Enemy's X axis is on is a multiple of 10. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

`(PlayerX >= EnemyX and PlayerX<= Enemyx +10 And PlayerY >= EnemyY And PlayerY <= EnemyY +10)`

```
change the code where it says plyaerX= enemy and change it to the above V full code
'Player and Enemy Variables
PlayerX = 0
PlayerY = 339
EnemyX = Math.GetRandomNumber(590)
EnemyY = 339
player = Shapes.AddRectangle(10, 10)
Enemy = Shapes.AddRectangle(10, 10)
Shapes.Move(player, PlayerX, PlayerY)
 Shapes.Move(enemy, EnemyX, EnemyY)
'Just setting up
GraphicsWindow.Show()
GraphicsWindow.Width = "600"
GraphicsWindow.Height = "400"
GraphicsWindow.KeyDown = OnKeyDown
'Ground, Enemy, and Player Drawn
GraphicsWindow.FillRectangle(0,350,600,50)

GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(50,50,100,"WASD")
Sub OnKeyDown
  'What button was pressed? 
  If (GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "W") Then

    PlayerY = PlayerY - 10
   Shapes.Move(player, PlayerX, PlayerY)
 Shapes.Move(enemy, EnemyX, EnemyY)

  EndIf
  If (GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "S") Then

    PlayerY = PlayerY + 10
    Shapes.Move(player, PlayerX, PlayerY)
 Shapes.Move(enemy, EnemyX, EnemyY)

  EndIf
  If (GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "A") Then

    PlayerX = PlayerX - 10
   Shapes.Move(player, PlayerX, PlayerY)
 Shapes.Move(enemy, EnemyX, EnemyY)

  EndIf
  If (GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "D") Then

    PlayerX = PlayerX + 10
    Shapes.Move(player, PlayerX, PlayerY)
 Shapes.Move(enemy, EnemyX, EnemyY)
    GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(50,50,100,"WASD")
  EndIf
  'Keep in the Graphics Window!
  If (PlayerX < 10) Then
    PlayerX = 10
  EndIf
  If (PlayerX > 590) Then
    PlayerX = 590
  EndIf
  If (PlayerY < 10) Then
    PlayerY = 10
  EndIf
  If (PlayerY > 339) Then
   PlayerY = 339
  EndIf
  'Player and Enemy Collide.
  If (PlayerX >= EnemyX and PlayerX<= Enemyx +10 And PlayerY >= EnemyY And PlayerY <= EnemyY +10) Then
    GraphicsWindow.DrawBoundText(100,50,100,"NO!")
  EndIf

EndSub'
```

Comment: enemyy and x[enemy] are +10 to accomidate the area of the square. so if it falls anywhere in the enemy it will initiate the NO! program. good job tho im gonna see if i can shorten your code or make it more efficient

Comment: you could use shapes instead. let me porivde the code.

Comment: I'm new to Small Basic so I didn't realize you could do shapes and move them around without having to clear and redraw the graphics screen. But the new code's cleaner and more effective

Comment: yeah. its better than graphics. use graphics if tghey will NEVER CHANGE and you wont have to wipe the screen. if you have to move a "shape" around use shapes.add then your shape. then you can move it around and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the random number always be a multiple of 10:

```
EnemyX = Math.GetRandomNumber(59)*10
```

Comment: right but then your limiting your self to multiples of 10 and the space is divided by 10.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this rather easily ( Completely Rewritten the Code)

```
'Show Graphics Window and some settings
GraphicsWindow.Show()
GraphicsWindow.BackgroundColor = "DarkBlue"
GraphicsWindow.Width = "600"
GraphicsWindow.Height = "400"
GraphicsWindow.CanResize = "False"
GraphicsWindow.KeyDown = OnKeyDown

'Ground
GraphicsWindow.FillRectangle(0,350,630,75)

'Set Player and Coordinates
Player = Shapes.AddRectangle(10, 10) 
PX = 0
PY = 340
Shapes.Move(Player,PX,PY)

'Set Enemy and Coordinates
Enemy = Shapes.AddEllipse(10, 10)
EX = Math.GetRandomNumber(300)
EY = 340
Shapes.Move(Enemy,EX,EY)


RunLoop:
GraphicsWindow.KeyDown = OnKeyDown

'Did Player and Enemy Collide?
If (EX <= PX + 10) Then
  Shapes.HideShape(Enemy)
EndIf

'Stay in Graphics Window Please!
If PX < 10 Then
  PX = 10
EndIf
If PX > 590 Then
  PX = 590
EndIf

Goto RunLoop

'Move Player
Sub OnKeyDown
  If(GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "A") Then
    PX = PX - 10
    Shapes.Move(Player,PX,PY)
  EndIf
  If(GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "D") Then
    PX = PX + 10
    Shapes.Move(Player,PX,PY)
  EndIf
EndSub
```